# Creating trigger which throws an exception on insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have few university tasks for winter break and one of them is to create trigger on table:

```
PERSON(ID, Name, Surname, Age);
```

Trigger is supposed to inform user when they have inserted row with invalid ID. Validity criteria is that ID is 11 digits long.

I tried to write solution like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_id_trigg
AFTER INSERT
ON person
DECLARE
  idNew VARCHAR(50);
  lengthException EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT id INTO idNew FROM INSERTED;
  IF LENGTH(idNew) <> 11 THEN
  RAISE lengthException;
  END IF;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN lengthException THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('ID for new person is INVALID. It must be 11 digits long!'); 
END;
```

Then I realized that INSERTED exists only in SQL Server and not in oracle.

What can I could do to fix that?

Comment: Use `BEFORE INSERT`, not `AFTER INSERT`. Use `FOR EACH ROW` clause. Don't execute any query, just check `new.id`. Read this link for details, there are many examples there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#LNPLS020

Comment: Thank you for input, clearly I need to read this documentation in order to understand triggers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to raise an exception (which would prevent the insert from succeeding)?  Or do you want to allow the insert to succeed and write a string to the `dbms_output` buffer that may or may not exist and may or may not be shown to a human running the insert?

In either case, you'll want this to be a row-level trigger, not a statement-level trigger, so you'll need to add the `for each row` clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_id_trigg
  AFTER INSERT
  ON person
  FOR EACH ROW
```

If you want to raise an exception

```
BEGIN
  IF( length( :new.id ) <> 11 )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
                             'The new ID value must have a length of 11' );
  END IF;
END;
```

If you want to potentially print output but allow the `insert` to succeed

```
BEGIN
  IF( length( :new.id ) <> 11 )
  THEN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'The new ID value must have a length of 11' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Of course, in reality, you would never use a trigger for this sort of thing.  In the real world, you would use a constraint.

Comment: Thanks for answer however when I try to compile it I get this error:Error report -
ORA-04082: NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers
04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
*Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
*Action:   Remove any new or old references.

Comment: @Roff - I missed the fact that you had declared the trigger as a statement-level trigger rather than a row-level trigger.  Added that to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for help, I've missunderstood usage of triggers clearly. Now it works fine.