# Making a trigger with RAISERROR

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have to make a trigger to fire an error state ment when the price and quatity are less than or equal to 0.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER doublecheck BEFORE INSERT
ON franzer_product
FOR EACH ROW
IF (new.price <= 0) THEN
BEGIN
RAISERROR ('The price you have entered cannot be zero or less than zero');
END;
IF (new.quantity <= 0) THEN
BEGIN
RASIERROR ('The quantity you have entered cannot be zero or less than zero')
END;
END;
```

I keep getting ERROR at line 4:

> ORA-04079 invalid trigger specification

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error. IF needs to be inside the BEGIN block. See https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php. Also, see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1042180 for exception handling and raising errors.

Comment: Does this help? [Creating trigger which throws an exception on insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892659/creating-trigger-which-throws-an-exception-on-insert)

Comment: If this is not a homework assignment, you'd be much better off with `check` constraints on both columns that enforce this sort of requirement rather than writing a trigger.  `raiserror` is a T-SQL function, not part of PL/SQL.  As the duplicate thread discusses, you'd want to use `raise_application_error` in PL/SQL.